# C# Compiled expression to create new instance of T and copy values to its properties from another instance of T

Tags: c#, lambda, reflection, expression

I would like to know if it is possible to create an instance of a type known only at runtime and assign values to the properties of this instance by using compiled expressions and if so how it is to be done.

I have a generic class with a method which accepts an instance of T and returns a copy. T is only known at runtime or rather is user/consumer defined. I know how to do so with reflection (assuming it has an empty constructor in this example and without exception handling or null checks for simplification).

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public T CreateCopy(T source)
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        var copy = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);
        foreach(var pi in type.GetProperties())
        {
            pi.SetValue(copy, pi.GetValue(source));
        }
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Reflection is quite expensive and after some digging i found an option to at least create an instance of T with compiled expressions.

```
var type = typeof(T);
Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(Expression
   .New(type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes)
       ?? throw new InvalidOperationException(
           $"Type has to have an empty public constructor. {type.Name}")))
   .Compile();
```

After some benchmarking i have found out that it performs around 6 times faster than the CreateCopy(...) method. The thing is that i do not know which type will be passed in as a generic and how many properties it will have.
Is there a way to do all of the operations from CreateCopy(...) method with compiled expressions?

Ihave looked into **Expression.Asign**, **Expression.MemberInit** but i am not able to find anything appropriate. The problem with **Expression.MemberInit** ist that it expects to have an **Expresssion.Bind** and **Expression.Constant** but i cant get the values of the properties from the passed instance of T into it. Is there a way?

Thank you.

P.S. So i am looking for something like:

```
var type = typeof(T);
var propertyInfos = type.GetProperties();
var ctor = Expression.New(type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
var e = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, T>>(Expression
            .MemberInit(ctor, propertyInfos.Select(pi => 
                Expression.Bind(pi, Expression.Constant(pi.GetValue(source)))))).Compile();
```

Comment: just so you know, this will not work on any arbitrary type, and seem a rather dangerous thing to do in production code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. What you need is to define a parameter and then assign the properties with property access expression like below :

```
public static T Express<T>(T source)
{
   var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "source");
   var type = typeof(T);
   var ctor = Expression
              .New(type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
   var propertyInfos = type.GetProperties();
   var e = Expression
            .Lambda<Func<T, T>>(
              Expression
              .MemberInit(ctor, propertyInfos.Select(pi =>
                   Expression.Bind(pi, CanBeAssigned(pi.PropertyType)
                    ? (Expression)Expression.Property(parameter, pi.Name)
                    : Expression.Call(typeof(Program).GetMethod(nameof(Express))
                                   .MakeGenericMethod(pi.PropertyType),                                                                        
                                  Expression.Property(parameter, pi.Name)
                          ))
                 )),
                parameter
            );
            var x = e.Compile();
            var z = x(source);
            return z;
}

public static bool CanBeAssigned(Type t)
{
    return t.IsValueType || t.Name == "String"; // this might need some improvements
}
```

Comment: Thank you! 2 questions:
1) You have created ´´´var props = propertyInfos.Select(r => Expression.Property(ctor, r.Name));´´´ but it is never used. What ist it for?
2) By shallow copy you mean that if the properties are reference types themselves, then you only copy a reference, or?

Comment: @Apolonius Well, the first one is a typo I have inlined that and forget to delete it and for the second one yes it only copies a reference for ref type objects.

Comment: That clarifies it. Thank you very much. My mistake was not to give "parameter" to the lambada like this Expression.Lambda<>(..., parameter);
So close yet so far :)

Comment: @Apolonius updated answer to handle deep clean(ish) scenarios.